# How to constrain a type to a subset of another?

Tags: scala, types

I have that *this is a dumb question* feeling, but here goes ... Can I define a type that is a subset of the elements of a another type? Here's a simplified example.

```
scala> class Even(i: Int) {
     | assert(i % 2 == 0)  
     | }
defined class Even

scala> new Even(3)
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
```

This is a runtime check. Can I define a type such that this is checked at compilation? IE, that the input parameter `i` is provably always even?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Value-dependent typing in languages such as Coq and Agda can do this, though not Scala.

Depending on the exact use-case, there are ways of encoding peano numbers in the type system that may, however, help you.

You might also want to try defining both `Even` and `Odd` along with some sealed abstract supertype (`OddOrEven` perhaps) and a factory method that returns the correct instance from any given Integer.

Another possibility is to define `Even` as an extractor.

Comment: C# can do a limited version of this at compile time.

Comment: You can define `Even.apply` such that it yields an `Odd` when approprite. Just kidding...